# Find out the list of recently run stored procs with start and end times

Tags: sql-server, database

Does anyone know if there is a built in command in sql server to find out the list of stored procs that  ran recently (lets say in the last two hours).
I tried different articles in web but none has satisfactory answer or do we have to write our own custom query to achieve this>

Thanks

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ???

Comment: If the cache has been flushed, I don't think you can find that information, otherwise look up [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx)

Comment: @KrishnrajRana i am using SQLServer2012

Comment: @abhi i'll have a look into it. Thanks

Comment: Hope this query might help you. **SELECT
    DatabaseName        = DB_NAME(st.dbid)
    ,SchemaName         = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid,dbid)
    ,StoredProcedure    = OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,dbid), cp.last_execution_Time
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
WHERE DB_NAME(st.dbid) IS NOT NULL and cp.last_execution_Time >= '2014-02-19 10:14:45.590'**. I'm not sure it satisfied your needs and that's why i have posted it in comment.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana wow if you could add the duration as well... that is exactly what i needed. Please feel free to post the updated query as the answer

Comment: I have updated it. Please check and comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query might help you.

```
SELECT DatabaseName = DB_NAME(st.dbid)
    , SchemaName = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid, dbid)
    , StoredProcedure = OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, dbid)
    , cp.last_execution_Time
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
WHERE DB_NAME(st.dbid) IS NOT NULL
    AND cp.last_execution_Time >= '2014-02-19 10:14:45.590'
```

Comment: is it possible to get the duration as well as to how long each stored proc ran for?

Comment: For that you can use **last_clr_time** column of dm_exec_query_stats DMV. See in detail about [dm_exec_query_stats here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a procedure log table and CREATE PROCEDURE to insert on it each time procedure executes.

```
create table proc_log
(
id int IDENTITY,
proc_name varchar(100),
start_time time(7),
end_time time(7)
)

create PROCEDURE proc_log_insert(@proce_name varchar(100),@s_time time(7),@e_time time(7))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PROC_LOG(PROC_NAME,START_TIME,END_TIME)
    VALUES(@PROC_NAME,@START_tIME,@END_TIME)
END

CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLE (...)
AS
DECLARE @S_TIME=CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME(7))
DECLARE @E_TIME
.
.
.
.
.
.
SET @E_TIME=CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME(7))
EXEC PROC_LOG_INSERT 'SAMPLE',@S_TIME,@E_TIME
END
```

Comment: this is one of the way to do so for the queries that you will be running later. However is there a way to check for those queries that you have run in the past?

Comment: You can use sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats dmv . take care that this data is since last server start and not the past.

Comment: Thanks Amirreza. I think writing the stored proc to log it would be a better approach as i dont think there is an inbuilt command provided by sql server for now.